# Using one cout command to print multiple strings with each string placed on a different (text editor) line

Tags: c++, string, cout

Take a look at the following example:

`cout << "option 1: 
          \n option 2:
          \n option 3";`

I know,it's not the best way to output a string,but the question is why does this cause an error saying that a " character is missing?There is a single string that must go to stdout but it just consists of a lot of whitespace charcters.

What about this:

`string x="
            string_test";`

One may interpret that string as: "\nxxxxxxxxxxxxstring_test" where x is a whitespace character.

Is it a convention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called `multiline string literal`.

You need to escape the embedded newline. Otherwise, it will not compile:

```
std::cout << "Hello world \
         and stackoverflow";
```

**Note:** Backslashes must be immediately before the line ends as they need to escape the newline in the source.

Also you can use the fun fact `"Adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler"` for your advantage by this:

```
std::cout << "Hello World"
"Stack overflow";
```

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) for `raw string literals`. In C++11, we have `raw string literals`. They are kind of like [here-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Syntax:

```
prefix(optional) R"delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"
```

> It allows any character sequence, except that it must not contain the
>   closing sequence `)delimiter"`. It is used to avoid escaping of any
>   character. Anything between the delimiters becomes part of the string.

```
const char* s1 = R"foo(
    Hello
    World
    )foo";
```

Example taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).